# What is the difference between foreach(println) and foreach(println())?

Tags: scala, eta-expansion

I have a string array:

```
val str:Array[String] = Array("aa","bb")
scala> str.foreach(println) // works
aa
bb
scala> str.foreach(println()) // println() also returns a Unit, doesn't it?
                          ^
error: type mismatch;
found   : Unit
required: String => ?
```

Why does `str.foreach(println)` work with no problem, but `str.foreach(println())` doesn't?
Isn't `println` equivalent to `println()` which returns a `Unit` value?

Comment: `foreach` expects a **function** from **String** to **Unit**. - `println` is a **method** with many overloaded versions. - **Scala** has something called _eta-expansion_ which allows to implicitly convert a **method** to a **function** when one is expected. Thus `foreach(println)` is equivalent to `foreach(s => println(s))`, which compiles. On the other hand `foreach(println())` is just an empty print, which has type **Unit** which is not what `foreach` expects, thus it does not compiles.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez That is, foreach(s => println(s)) is equivalent to foreach(println(_)) which is equivalent to foreach(println) due to eta-expansion, correct?
The println argument in foreach is actually println(_) that has an argument, howerver println() has no argument even both of them return a Unit value. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`println` is a method (convertible to a function) that takes input (`String` in this case) and produces a result (`Unit`) and a side-effect (printing to StdOut).

`println()` is the invocation of a method that takes no input, produces a result (`Unit`), and a side-effect (`\n` to StdOut).

They aren't the same.

The 2nd one won't work in a `foreach()` because `foreach()` feeds elements (strings in this case) to its argument and `println()` won't take the input that `foreach()` is feeding it.

This will work `str.foreach(_ => println())` because the underscore-arrow (`_ =>`) says: "Ignore the input. Just throw it away and invoke what follows."

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are missing the underscore. Try this

```
str.foreach(println(_))
```